# Tomcat java web application got running slowly

Tags: java, performance, web-services, tomcat, virtual-machine

Don't know which way of investigation should select.
After some time (near 4 weeks) on continouous running web application got run slowly.
Checking:

```
catalina.out - no full gc.
```

Regular gc takes near 0.2s and executed one time in near 10  - 30 seconds.
On the same server another tomcat with web application running well.
So the problem not in the host. 
I am really confused. What should be checked ?

Comment: In common no. Young gen increases and decreases according to provided services. Old gen near 80 - 90 % and don't cleaned, don't increased. So nothing unusual.

Answer (score 1):

you can use a `visualvm` to track you tomcat performance, you have to add the JMX parameters to allow you to connect the visualvm to you your tomcat.

```
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.authenticate=false
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.port=8484
-Dcom.sun.management.jmxremote.ssl=false
```

In the `visualvm` >> `Threads` Tab you will see a button in the above right corner `Thread Dump`, this button generates a file called thread dump, this file contains the whole threads that currently live, generate a multiple thread dumps and trace you application threads, you will clearly see what does the slow thread is currently doing, which exactly the method caused that slowness.

I hope this help you to get the root cause for your slowness.